# javax.smartcardio case 4 APDU vanishing - 6700 response - warning

Tags: java, smartcard, apdu

Using javax.smartcardio classes for smartcard programming, I encountered a persistent error - getting back 6700 (invalid length) and similar error codes from the card when the code looked fine. Example code:

```
    req = new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, aid, 0x00);
```

This is supposed to construct a case 4 APDU. Why does the card respond as if I were missing something?

Comment: What _similar error codes_ does the card response? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: What is in the `aid` array? Could you please post a little more of your code?

Comment: @vojta: what details could you tell from the contents of the AID array except if you know the cardlet?

Comment: AID too short, AID too long, incorrect data in the array because of a bug... I do not know...

Comment: @vojta: similar error codes: "0x6c00 Wrong length"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
>    req = new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, aid, 0x00);
> ```
>
> This is supposed to construct a case 4 APDU. Why does the card respond as if I were missing something?

### Short answer

Use `aid, 0x100` instead of `aid, 0x00`.

### Long answer (better get some coffee):

That's because of the confusion between `Ne` and `Le`. `Ne` is the *maximum* amount of bytes that can be returned to the terminal. `Ne` is a number without specific representation. `Le` however is the *encoding* or *representation in bytes* of `Ne`.

Now for ISO/IEC 7816-4 there is a little trick: `Le` is absent (no bytes) in case of an ISO case 1 or 3 command without response data (RDATA). So defining `Le = 00` to mean "no response data" is spurious. Instead 7816-4 uses `Le = 00` to mean `Ne = 256`. Similarly, `Le = 0000` (or `Le = 000000`) means `Ne = 65536`, i.e. 2^16. The double and triple byte encoding are only used for extended length APDU's.

As you can see in the [`CommandAPDU` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/CommandAPDU.html) however you have to specify `Ne`, not `Le`. What you specify is therefore the same as saying that there is no response data. So the APDU will not be interpreted correctly as an ISO case 4 and the command will fail (correctly in this case, `6700` is exactly what you should expect).

So just specify how many bytes you expect. If the value is larger than 256 then an extended length APDU will be required (or command chaining, but that's a topic in itself). `Ne < 0` or `Ne > 64Ki` is of course not supported.

---

Note that many protocol descriptions *including the Java Card API* got the distinction between `Ne` and `Le` wrong (this has been fixed in [the Java Card API v3.0.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/index.html) by the way). That's kind of strange as there are many **many** issues with 7816-4, but this is not one of them. It's specified pretty clearly.